# How to determine if a given sample size is appropriate for Betti number estimation?

Tags: sample-size, small-sample, topological-data-analysis

A popular approach in topological data analysis is persistent homology ([Chazal and Michel 2021](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2021.667963/full) for an intro), but it is not clear to me what sample sizes are appropriate. Some talks seem to use samples of $10^4-10^6$ for real data, and for demos I have seen as few as 50-100 points successfully identify the right Betti numbers in a preset number of dimensions.

I am not confident that the field of topological data analysis is ready to definitely answer this question as the various heuristic choices already go into these analyses, but I am also quite new to the subject myself having only read a little more than a dozen papers on it. Even if provided with a density function describing the sampling (e.g. uniform), it is still non-obvious to me how we would decide that the amount of data is sufficient. It has the feeling of being a poorly-specified problem, and yet it is a practical concern in analyzing a real data set.

Are there any mathematical or simulation results looking at evaluating if a given sample is even large enough to get the right Betti numbers? Either Vietoris-Rips or Cech complexes are fine.